# How to authenticate and authorize Java application with KeyCloak

Tags: java, servlets, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a Java servlet that accepts HTTP requests, "protected" by KeyCloak. I can manually send a GET request, which redirects me to the KeyCloak login page, and I can log in and see the correct webpage from the servlet. Now I would like to make it such that my other Java application can also authenticate itself and access the webpage.

In my current setup I have the Java servlet running in Wildfly and the keycloak standalone. I have a KeyCloak realm with a user "testuser" with the role "testrole" and client "testclient". To be fair I don't really know what the client does, since it has no role or other attributes set. Should it represent the servlet application or the requesting Java application? What attributes should I set here?

The documentation mentiones JWT Tokens, but I don't know how I can obtain one. The actual request should be to "localhost:8080/testservlet" , do I have to query for a token at the KeyCloak server first, or should I go through the redirect process as when it is "manual"?

Comment: This is defined in the RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749%5D . You need to follow the steps in the flow as defined.

Comment: The [KeyCloak getting started guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/index.html) walks through this very well.

Comment: I completed the getting started guide, but it's not what I need. I don't want to manually log in every time, but allow my second Java application to authenticate itself. I would think this (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_client_authentication_adapter) part should be helpful, but I can't really connect it to what I have.